How to update to PHP 7.4 on Debian buster - _without_ Sury packages?
Before I can move my wikis from an old Debian 10 (Buster) server with PHP 7.3, I need to upgrade the wiki - and this demands PHP 7.4.
Various howtos describe the process to update to PHP 7.4 on buster, using the packages at sury.org.
Only, the wise guy there removed the buster files, maybe to remind people to update.
Asking for all in the same situation - needing an intermediate update to PHP 7.4 on buster - how can this be done without sury packages?

Like compiling from the source code? https://github.com/php/php-src/releases/tag/php-7.4.31

Manually adjusting all debian dependencies?

Updating from buster (10) to bullseye (11) prooved to be the solution. The latter brings PHP 7.4, taking all existing extensions into account.
Then the wiki-Upgrade worked, the folder copied to the new (bookworm) server runs without hassle.
